# What does "dead" and "buck" mean?

Tags: word-meaning, slang

In a youtube video, the interviewer asked, "What happened to your business?"

The interviewee replied with, "It was basically **dead** and the economy was literally like a **buck** a day."

I looked up the word *dead*, and definitions I found were only things that had passed away. Is the word *buck* singular for 'bucks' as in money?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definitions for both words are correct. Note that "dead" is used in a figurative sense, meaning that there is no activity. (Some dictionaries might give that as a literal meaning.)

Comment: Oh, uhh. Thank you!